# Margin issue with IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have a CSS for body tag but it doesn't contain any margin property. but IE 9 shows margin-bottom ad left,right, top as 0 and due to bottom margin my layout is broken. If i take developer tool and uncheck that property the my layout is fine . any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have JS setting the `margin-bottom`? If not, what's stopping you from setting it to zero with CSS?

Comment: This is why a reset style sheet is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your body margin property to:

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

And check, if thats helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this really is the only browser you're having trouble with, use an IE 9 Conditional Comment after your style tag and above the head tag, for example on specific element or html document as whole:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>
#someElementId {margin-top: -33px}
html {margin-top: -33px}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thats not really a good solution, since we don't know, why do IE set this properly.

Answer (score 0):

The `body` element typically has default margins of 8px on each side. This is even mentioned in the [default style sheet for HTML in the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html).

Should you wish to remove that, you can set

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

in your own style sheet.